# Starting application on C2DM message

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

i have an app that sends a c2dm message to another device, I am wondering how could I start a certain activity or application when the c2dm message is recieved? Can I send an intent to do this in a c2dm message or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you can start an activity while receiveing c2dm message.you can't send an intent from your server.you can send 4kb text messages only.

Comment: is there sample code for starting an activity on recieving a c2dm message? thanks

Comment: try this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Put this code where you handle the incoming message from C2DM.

```
Intent myActivity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
myActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(myActivity);
```

Be sure, you have declared your activity in manifest.